# How to find 7 consecutive non zero values in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

If we have a table of 15 columns, the first one is id, and the other columns have numeric
data type,
in MySQL or a similar languages, how can I find if the record have 7 consecutive non zero values, meaning that 7 of the contiguous columns have a value not equals to zero?

We can write a query has a lot of OR operations to check that each 7 columns don't have 0 value, but I want to know if there is shorter way

Comment: If you are comparing columns this way, they really shouldn't be stored in different columns; instead have each value in a row of its own, with a field number column to indicate which value it is.

Comment: No, we need them separated for another reason.

Comment: no, you really don't.  selecting the format you have from the model you should have is trivial.

Comment: I don't have to describe the whole senario dear, here is the case I have and I need a solution for this one.

Comment: There is plenty of ways to do so, but the most easy one is to write 6 OR... But I am supicious to know why do you have those 7 consecutive columns... Are they days of week ? Did you normalize your database ?

Comment: c1 * c2 * c3 etc will return 0 only if one of the columns is 0. However, overflow/underflow can be a problem - but I don't know your data.

Comment: Yes @SQLpro. they are 7 days and I'm joining two records to get the consecutive 14 days

Comment: @jarlh what do you mean by overflow/underflow?

Comment: So to have a much faster way to do so you need to normalize your data by creating a sub table with a key column, a fkey from the actual table, a column with the number of the day from 1 to 7 and a column with the value. Then the query will be trivial like : SELECT fkey FROM MyTable WHERE "value" = 0 GROUP BY fkey HAVING COUNT(*) = 7

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: with 15 columns, the query will be : SELECT fkey FROM MyTable WHERE "value" = 0 GROUP BY fkey HAVING COUNT(*) = 7 AND SUM(POWER(2, numday-1)) IN (127, 254, 508, 1016, 2032, 4064, 8128, 16256, 32512)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following using `CONCAT` and `INSTR` functions, explanation is within query comments:

```
/*
check if the col value is not equal to 0, 
this will return 1 if true and 0 if false,
and concatenate all of the returned values.
*/
with concat_cols as
(
  select *, 
   concat(             
     col1<>0, col2<>0, col3<>0, col4<>0, col5<>0, 
     col6<>0, col7<>0, col8<>0, col9<>0, col10<>0, 
     col11<>0, col12<>0, col13<>0, col14<>0, col15<>0
   ) as con_col
  from table_name
)
/* 
using the instr function, check if the concatenated
result contains 7 consecutive 1s (7 not 0 values).
*/
select * from concat_cols
where instr(con_col, repeat('1', 7))
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-rlRlNoG)

Comment: what a great way, finally, thanks!!

Comment: thats very nice

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
field(0,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7) = 0 or
field(0,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8) = 0 or
field(0,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9) = 0 or
field(0,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10) = 0 or
field(0,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11) = 0 or
field(0,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12) = 0 or
field(0,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13) = 0 or
field(0,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14) = 0 or
field(0,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15) = 0
```

Comment: What about negative values? -1 is less than 0, but still not 0.

Comment: right, this wouldn't work if data could be null or is signed

Comment: @jarlh fixed for negatives.  not sure how they want nulls treated

Comment: the values should not be null, thanks @ysth

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id
 FROM your_table
 WHERE SUM(CASE WHEN column_2 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN column_3 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN column_4 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN column_5 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN column_6 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN column_7 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN column_8 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 7
```

Comment: Manga we can use aggregation function in select lists in order by or in having clause not in the where clause.